# Sharing text in LinkedIin showing unsuccessful message

Tags: ios, swift, linkedin-api, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

Using native sharing text feature by UIActivityViewController. 
Its successfully posting on **share in a post**, able to see in my LinkedIn page but showing error message in UI.

```
    let text = "This is the text....."
    let textShare = [ text ]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: textShare , applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Attached image below, please have a look.

[image]